# How to print average of a list on x axis?

Tags: matplotlib, plot

So I have a huge list of 446 item 
and with rotation set to 90 I can only fit 98, according to my monitor size on X axis

```py
y = list_price
x = list_dates

finx = [] 

for index, meat in enumerate(x):
    if index % 5 == 0:
        finx.append(meat)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x)))
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
plt.show()
```

This code ^ prints the **first** 98 items 
but if I change MultipleLocator to 1, it create a mess maybe because I didn't understood it much.
So what I wanted to do is to put average of all list_dates so that it covers from start to end  i.e finx.

Comment: Most certainly you forgot to convert your strings to numbers.

Comment: I dont want to they are dates in the format dd-mon-yy